# Show the the equivalence between $v^H W v = 0$ and $W v=0$

Tags: matrix-decomposition

Can someone help me to prove the equivalence between $v^{H}W v = 0$ and $W v=0$, where $W$ is positive-semidefinite?

I can finish the part: $W v=0 \rightarrow v^HWv = 0$.

But the inverse part: $v^HWv = 0 \rightarrow Wv=0$, I cannot find ways to prove.

Can anyone help me to show the inverse part?

Comment: The statement cannot be proven because it is obviously incorrect for an arbitrary square matrix. Take for example matrix $W=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1\end{bmatrix}$ and vector $v = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}$. Then $v^TWv=0$ and $Wv = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ -1\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: The question specifically states that W is positive semidefinite, @AndreZege, which your W is not. Your answer correctly address the thread title (which does not mention W being  positive semidefinite), but not the body of the question.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming $W$ is positive semidefinite, it has orthogonal eigenvectors $w_{i}$ and corresponding non-negative eigenvalues $\lambda_{i}$. Then, from expanding $v$ into the basis of eigenvectors $v=\sum \alpha_{i} w_{i}$ one finds $Q=v^T W v = \sum \alpha_{i}^{2} \lambda_{i}$. From $Q=0$, follows that $\alpha_{i}=0$ for all $\lambda_{i} > 0$. Only $\alpha_{i}$ corresponding to $\lambda_{i}=0$. could be non-zero. Hence $W v=0$.

Answer (score 1):

The statement $ W \mathbf{v} = \mathbf{0}$ says that vector $\mathbf{v}$ belongs to the [null space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(linear_algebra)) of $W$.

Let's assume for a moment a symmetric transformation $W^\frac{1}{2}$ exists. Then the statement $\mathbf{v}' W \mathbf{v} = 0$ is equivalent to saying
$ \|W^\frac{1}{2} \mathbf{v} \| = 0$, which (by [def. of a norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)#Definition))  is the same as as saying $W^\frac{1}{2} \mathbf{v} = \mathbf{0}$ and $\mathbf{v}$ belongs to the null space of $W^\frac{1}{2}$.

The existence of a self-adjoint $W^\frac{1}{2}$ with the same null space as $W$ can be shown via the [spectral theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem#Finite-dimensional_case).

The spectral theorem allows you to write $W$ as:

$$ W = P D P'$$

Where $D = \begin{bmatrix} \lambda_1 & 0 & \ldots \\ 0 & \lambda_2 & \ldots \\ \ldots \end{bmatrix}$ is a diagonal matrix of eigenvalues and $P$ is an [orthogonal matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_matrix) (whose columns are eigenvectors). Then $W^\frac{1}{2} = P D ^ \frac{1}{2} P'$. The eigenvectors with zero eigenvalues are the same for $W$ and $W^\frac{1}{2}$ hence they have the same null space.

#### References

Axler, Sheldon. *Linear Algebra Done Right*, 1991

Comment: Are you sure for any symmetric matrix $W$, there exists $W^{\frac{1}{2}}$ such that $W^{\frac{1}{2}}$ is also symmetric??

Comment: @Dony Yes, your operator is [positive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive_element#Positive_and_positive_definite_operators) (also referred to as positive semi-definite).

Comment: The argument assumes that $W$ is positive definite, if only semi-definite not.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen What argument assumes positive definite? I've only assumed the operator is positive (which is *not* the same as positive definite). There's nothing wrong with eigenvalues of 0. The real spectral theorem (on a real inner product space) only requires that a linear operator is self-adjoint.

Comment: That is true, but when $W$ has a zero eigenvalue, $\mid \mid W^{1/2} x \mid\mid$ does not define a norm, only a pseudonorm. Take $x \not = 0$ as an eigenvector with eifenvalue 0, then $W^{1/2} x = 0$, so is not a norm.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Let $\mathbf{z} = W^{\frac{1}{2}} \mathbf{x}$. Observe $\mathbf{z}$ is a vector and I'm taking the usual $L_2$ norm $\|\mathbf{z}\|_2 = \sqrt{\sum_i z_i^2}$ of that vector. I'm *not* using $W$ to define a norm $\| . \|_W$  (and I agree with you, that would be a mistake because it would fail $\|\mathbf{x}\|_W=0$ iff $\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{0}$).

Comment: @Kjetil You are right to be concerned about the lack of positive definiteness.  However, Matthew's argument requires only that the eigenvalues have real square roots--and that obviously is true even of semi-definite quadratic forms.